# Python - Error when inserting data (TypeError: Object of type 'int64' is not JSON serializable)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, salesforce

I am trying to insert a few records from my Dataframe to Salesforce but get an error

```
TypeError: Object of type 'int64' is not JSON serializable
```

Given below is the code I am using:

```
if len(acct) > 0:
    list = []
    for i in range(len(acct)):
        update = {'Id': acct['Id'].iloc[i],
              'name': acct['user_count'].iloc[i]}

        list.append(update)
    sf_data_cursor.bulk.Account.update(list)
```

Given below is the data type of the column:

```
Column: user_count is of type int64
```

Could anyone help find where I am going wrong. Thanks.

**Update:**

View of the Dataframe before inserting:

```
Id, Name, user_count
1, ABC, 10
2, XYZ, 13
```

Answer (score 0):

Field mapping is not correct here. Name field is not getting proper.

`update = {'Id': acct['Id'].iloc[i],
              'name': acct['user_count'].iloc[i]}`

Please try below code:

```
if len(acct) > 0:
    list = []
    for i in range(len(acct)):
        update = {'Id': acct['Id'].iloc[i],
              'name': acct['Name'].iloc[i]}

        list.append(update)
    sf_data_cursor.bulk.Account.update(list)
```

Let me know if this solves your issue.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I actually have two more fields that are text fields. I get the same error if I try to insert them. Just to confirm, you wanted to remove the label name without quotes right.

Comment: is this what you meant.

This however throws the error "KeyError: 0"

Comment: update = {'Id': acct['Id'].iloc[i],
              'name': acct[user_count].iloc[i]}

Comment: Please try updating only id first and let me know if update goes well.  i.e. `update = {'Id': acct['Id'].iloc[i]}`. And if this works, then try complete code and print the output of 'update' and reply what output you are getting.

Comment: I ran the code  

update = {'Id': acct['Id'].iloc[i]}   and it executed without errors.

Comment: Please see my updated reply and let me know if this works.

Comment: When I try to update the user_count column along with the id column, I get the error "TypeError: Object of type 'int64' is not JSON serializable" . I have included the view of the Dataframe in the initial post of this message.

Comment: Yes updating id with integer this will give you an error. Please see my updated reply and let me know if this works.

Comment: Please print the output of 'update' and reply what output you are getting. Print before line `list.append(update)'.

Comment: Its shows the output as expected when I try to do a print before the list.append(update)

Comment: output of the print statement is as below  {'Id': '1',
  'Name': ABC,
   'user_count': 10}

Comment: May you post reply here? Also confirm,  code looks like `update = {'Id': acct['Id'].iloc[i],
              'name': acct['Name'].iloc[i]}`

Comment: this is the output I receive     [{'Id': '1', 'Name': ABC}]

Comment: According to your reply `{'Id': '1', 'Name': ABC}`. 1 is inside quote, why ABC is not inside a quote. ABC should also be quoted. Could you please paste complete code?

Comment: Sorry mis-typed. Pasting the actual output again.

[{'Id': '1',
  'Name': 'ABC'},
{'Id': '12,
  'Name': 'XYZ'}]

Comment: Please run this code and let me know what you are getting: `list = []
update = {'Id': '001ascfbadrejasmek',
              'name': 'Test account'}

list.append(update)
sf_data_cursor.bulk.Account.update(list) `

Comment: [{'created': False,
  'errors': [{'extendedErrorDetails': None,
    'fields': ['Id'],
    'message': 'Account ID: id value of incorrect type: 001ascfbadrejasmek',
    'statusCode': 'MALFORMED_ID'}],
  'id': None,
  'success': False}]

Comment: Salesforce account id should start with `001` and goes upto 15/18 digit. So assigning '1' is anyway incorrect. I want to change your error message first. Service is working perfectly fine, as you are saying updating only id is working fine. Assignment which you are doing in your code is incorrect.

Comment: This is the line you have to correct. `'name': acct['Name'].iloc[i]'. You have to debug and check what you are getting in `acct['Name'].iloc[i]`.

Comment: I have modified the input and now get an error message   SalesforceMalformedRequest: Malformed request https://cs52.salesforce.com/services/async/38.0/job/7505B0000038V8dQAE/batch/7515B000003Qb49QAC/result. Response content: {'exceptionCode': 'InvalidBatch', 'exceptionMessage': 'Records not processed'}.

Comment: Previous request format was correct only assignment was incorrect. Due to change you have made, proper request format is not getting created correctly. Please undo to previous state and correct name assignment.